# Aligning a QTableWidgetItem causes item to be None

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have created a table in PyQt5 and populated it similar to how it's done in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017853/sqlite3-table-into-qtablewidget-sqlite3-pyqt5). I want to center align all the cells but when I try to align each cell my QTableWidgetItem becomes None.

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html)  `setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)` should work. See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum) too

Here is a working example where self.db_table is the QTableWidget.

```
for row in rows:
    inx = rows.index(row)
    self.db_table.insertRow(inx)
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1])))
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[2])))
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[3])))
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[4])))
```

And when I add the `setTextAlignment()` it makes all the QTableWidgetItems None:

```
for row in rows:
    inx = rows.index(row)
    self.db_table.insertRow(inx)
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter))
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1])).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter))
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[2])).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter))
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[3])).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter))
    self.db_table.setItem(inx, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[4])).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter))
```

Is there any reason why this isnt working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `setTextAlignment()` method does not return any parameters and that equals None, and then you are passing None to `setItem`, what you must do is create the item as `item = QTableWidgetItem({})` and then use `item.setTextAlignment({})` and at the end add it `self.db_table.setItem(inx, 0, item)` for each element, a reduced form is the following:

```
for row in rows:
    inx = rows.index(row)
    self.db_table.insertRow(inx)
    for i, v in zip(range(5), row):
        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(v))
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.db_table.setItem(inx, i, item)
```

Comment: Is a great solution, it help me a lot thanks @eyllanesc.